# JUnit5 Test Suite doesn't test all classes from a package

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5, suite

I've got a Suite class as follows:

```
package test.suite;

import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SuiteDisplayName;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SuiteDisplayName("JUnit Platform Suite Demo")
@SelectPackages("test")
public class Suite {

}
```

And two identical test classes (they differ only by their name at the moment) in the same package called test:

```
package test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class testClass1 {

    @Test
    void mainA() {
        assertTrue(42==42);
    }
```

When I hit run on 'Suite', only testClass1 will be tested and testClass2 is left out. What am I missing?

The Suite should test classes even recursively from other subpackages in the given package if I'm not mistaken.

--EDIT:
Initially I created two test classes for the same class, and the second test class gets ignored. If I add a third test class in the package, but this time for a separate class, that will get tested as expected.

Comment: Looks like a limitation of the API to me

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing same issue. I had several files and in my case when i do run as suite some of them would be included and other would not. It was pretty frustrating as I can run them fine individually.

It turned out the one that were not included were those whose name did not end with Test. For example, ClassA wouldn't be added but once i renamed to  ClassATest it got added when running as suite package feature.